# Intellij debugging: how to inspect member variables of a class that implements Map?

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea

Intellij debugging: how to inspect member variables of a class that implements Map? e.g.,

```
public class MyMap implement java.util.Map<String, Object> {
    private Object foo;
    private Object bar;

    ....


}


MyMap myMap = new MyMap();
myMap .put("hello", "world");
```

The debugger show only the entries in the map.

```
myMap (MyMap@123) size=1
   "hello" --> "world"
```

How to show the values of member variables foo and bar?

Comment: Could you please provide the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? I [can't reproduce it](https://i.imgur.com/vOzE1ag.png).

Comment: updated. Inside debugger, can not see the values of foo & bar. Intellij thinks there are only entries for map.

Comment: For reproduce, simply extends HashMap, and add some member variables.

Comment: Any difference if you disable the alternate collections view? Can you just upload and link a project on GitHub?

Comment: disable alternative view -- works. Thanks. IF you like to make it an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try disabling the **Alternate view for Collection classes** in File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Debugger | Data Views | Java.